# how to write Custom checks in checkstyle?

Tags: java, design-patterns, ant, checkstyle

I want to write a custom check for checkstyle.

my rule that i want to work with is
 Class should define a constructor- **but Suppress this rule for inner classes**

how should i go about writing this check.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom CheckStyle check by extending the `com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check` class, you then create a jar for this project and point CheckStyle to use it. I've written an example here:

http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/create-your-own-checkstyle-check/

and source code here:

https://github.com/blundell/CreateYourOwnCheckStyleCheck

Comment: It's outdated. `Check` is depracated now.

Comment: You can use `AbstractCheck` instead of `Check`