# Writing custom Lint rule to ensure null-check before every using to avoid NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lint

I want make a custom Lint rule to ensure null-check before every reference to a sever returned JavaBean object or its fields to avoid NullPointerException. For example:

**error case:**

```
SomeBean bean = fetchDataFromServer();
bean.getSomeField().doSomeThing();//-->Lint should report error, missing null-check before using
```

**right case:**

```
if (bean != null && bean.getSomeField() != null) {
    bean.getSomeField().doSomeThing();//-->Lint should check this ok, have checked for both reference
}
```

**My question**: Are there any implemented rules already for this check?  If no, could somebody give me some idea how to write one such custom rule?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you looked at `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` in android support annotations?

Comment: @Ironman its not a duplicate of that question. OP is not enquiring about fixing a NPE but how to generate lint rules to avoid it

Comment: @akash93 Yes. I have tried to find if there is related lint rule to handle these nullness annotations, but failed.  I intended to refer such rule to write a custom one that must obey.

Answer (score 1):

Among frequently used linters in the Java ecosystem:

1. [*SonarLint*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube#SonarLint) (also *SonarQube*) has a **rule to avoid NPE**
2. [*FindBugs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FindBugs) (also successor *SpotBugs*) has **bug patterns to detect NPE** (prefixed with `NP`)
3. [*Checkstyle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkstyle) allows to add a custom rule

#### SonarLint

There is the Sonar rule [RSPEC-2259](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2259) that deals with the [Law of Demeter (LoD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> **Null pointers should not be dereferenced**
>
> A reference to null should never be dereferenced/accessed. Doing so will cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. At best, such an exception will cause abrupt program termination. At worst, it could expose debugging information that would be useful to an attacker, or it could allow an attacker to bypass security measures.

You can use the free *SonarLint* plugin for your Java IDE (e.g. IntelliJ or Eclipse). To install the free IDE extension, visit the official website: [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/)

#### FindBugs

Among other bug-descriptions in the `NP` category, [`NP_ALWAYS_NULL`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_ALWAYS_NULL) for example:

> **NP: Null pointer dereference (NP_ALWAYS_NULL)**
>
> A null pointer is dereferenced here.  This will lead to a `NullPointerException` when the code is executed.

See also:

- [What is the meaning of Possible null pointer dereference in findbug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242291/what-is-the-meaning-of-possible-null-pointer-dereference-in-findbug#12242320)

#### Checkstyle

To write your own [checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/index.html) rule, see:

- [how to write Custom checks in checkstyle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471458/how-to-write-custom-checks-in-checkstyle)

#### Further Reading

- OWASP: [Null Dereference](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Null_Dereference)
- Baeldung: [Static Code Analysis](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-code-analysis-tutorial)
- Baeldung: [Intro to Code Quality Rules with FindBugs and PMD](https://www.baeldung.com/code-quality-metrics)